# Is it possible for hardcoded db details to be discovered

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, connection-string, credentials

Good evening all,

Apologies if this is a obvious question, but I was wondering the following...

If i publish an app in VB which connects to a mysql database with its connection string hardcoded, is it possible for an end user to somehow get hold of my connection string?

I obviously don't want my db user's credentials being discovered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is a remote SQL server, see [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112316/36214).

Comment: Thank you kindly! I was just figuring out how I'll do that with PHP :)

Comment: I assume this is an application for in-house? Considering they have direct access to the mysql  database. Before you undertake the pretty large project of making this a two tier app, why not make this a business problem instead of a technical one? You get the.credentials and login to the database directly and you are fired...

Comment: The app will run on remote machines anywhere on the web, reporting back to mysql. 
I've now build a php interface to act as an interface to my db. Luckily my app has just 3 functions for all db interaction,
I just need to amend these three functions to work with the PHP page and its problem solved. For each 'client' running the program, I generate a unique code which is passed to the php page. php checks if that code exists as a user. If not, the request is rejected and the browser redirects to a generic 403 page. I'm still so so thankful I decided to ask this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy, just open the app in Reflector.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
So how would one go about making this connection string safe?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. Even if you encrypt it and store it in the app.config, at some point it will be decrypted by your app, and a sophisticated user can grab it then.

Comment: Now, if you aren't worried about a sophisticated user, and just some random user then you probably don't even need to worry about Reflector. You could also encrypt the password and hope the user doesn't know how to pull the decryption keys, which would also be available via Reflector.

Comment: Thats pretty scary! I guess i'd kinda assumed that it would be safe until this point - so glad I decided to ask the question!
Thanks Chet